# is there a way to convert non-IPv4 address to country code in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, ip, ipv4

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    NET.IPV4_TO_INT64(NET.IP_FROM_STRING(context_ip)) AS clientIpNum,
    TRUNC(NET.IPV4_TO_INT64(NET.IP_FROM_STRING(context_ip))/(256*256)) AS classB
  FROM
    `product_table` AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  `fh-bigquery.geocode.geolite_city_bq_b2b` AS b
ON
  a.classB = b.classB
  AND a.clientIpNum BETWEEN b.startIpNum AND b.endIpNum
```

so i am trying to get the transfer the ip address to country, but seems not working , and i have the following error code

```
NET.IPV4_TO_INT64() encountered a non-IPv4 address. Expected 4 bytes but got 16
```

and the format of my context_ip is like this '173.170.166.0'
any one can help to convert the ip address to country code?

Answer (score 1):

This is the example from:
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/geolocation-with-bigquery-de-identify-76-million-ip-addresses-in-20-seconds

```sql
WITH source_of_ip_addresses AS (
  SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(contributor_ip, 'xxx', '0')  ip, COUNT(*) c
  FROM `publicdata.samples.wikipedia`
  WHERE contributor_ip IS NOT null  
  GROUP BY 1
),
test as (Select * from unnest(SPLIT("71.203.44.188 24.167.141.7 206.191.39.53 173.170.166.0"," ")) ip )


Select TBLA,country_name, city_name, subdivision_1_name
from (
    SELECT *, NET.SAFE_IP_FROM_STRING(ip) & NET.IP_NET_MASK(4, mask) network_bin
    FROM 
    #source_of_ip_addresses
    test
    , UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(9,32)) mask
    WHERE BYTE_LENGTH(NET.SAFE_IP_FROM_STRING(ip)) = 4
) TBLA
  JOIN `fh-bigquery.geocode.201806_geolite2_city_ipv4_locs`  
  USING (network_bin, mask)
```